# Fill shell script array in for loop

Tags: bash, scripts

I have a list of data that the user gives as arguments.

For simplicity-sake of the code that comes after the one shown, this code builds a relationship between the value inputted and the position it was inputted.

```
values=("${@:2}")
values2=()

for i in ${!values[@]}; do
    values2[${values[$i]}]="$i"
    echo "$values2"
done
echo $values2
```

This code worked in ubuntu 16.04 but doesn't work on ubuntu 18.04. I don't know what I'm missing.

In this code, no errors appear and, instead, at the end of this code snippet, the variable `values2` is always empty.
If I call this code using `thisscript param1 1600 2000 3000`, after that `for`, which is ran, `$values2` stays empty.

What is deleting `$values2`?

Comment: The indices of `values2` are the *values* of `values` i.e. 1600,2000,3000. Meanwhile, `$values2` is equivalent to `${values2[0]}` - but you haven't assigned anything to the 0th element. If you do `echo "${values2[*]}"` you should see non-empty values

Comment: I was testing it wrong. I should have used `"${values2[*]}"`. Thank you @steeldriver